# Select multiple minimum values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to show the loans which are borrowed the least. This is a case where two loans are tied in the smallest number of borrowers.

```
Loan:
no | type    
------------
L1 | house  
L2 | student
L3 | car    

Borrower ('num' is foreign key to 'no'):
name | num
----------
A    | L1
A    | L1
A    | L2
A    | L3

SELECT loan.type
FROM loan, borrower
WHERE loan.no = b.num
  AND loan.type = (SELECT MIN(type) from loan)
  GROUP BY loan.type
```

This should produce `student` and `car` but for now it's just giving me one of them. How should I modify my query to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method using a CTE:

```
WITH lb as (
      SELECT l.type, COUNT(b.num) as cnt
      FROM loan l LEFT JOIN
           borrower b
           ON l.no = b.num
      GROUP BY l.type
     )
SELECT lb.type
FROM lb
WHERE lb.cnt = (SELECT MIN(lb.cnt) FROM lb);
```

Notes:

- If you want the loan types with the fewest borrowers, then you should be comparing the *count*, not the *type*.
- The `LEFT JOIN` considers loan types with no borrowers.
- You need to learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Correction: loan types with the fewest borrowers. Ok, I will look into JOINing. Is there a way to reduce that code so it doesn't have that nesting?

Comment: @maregor . . . This is probably the simplest way to write the query in SQLite.